# Changing "/" to "\" [C#]

Tags: c#

I have already seen the other way around. But this one I can not catch. I am trying to get a part of a web resourcePath and combine it with a local path.
Let me Explain a bit more.

```
public string GetLocalPath(string URI, string webResourcePath, string folderWatchPath) // get the folderwatcher path to work in the local folder
    {
        string changedPath = webResourcePath.Replace(URI, "");
        string localPathTemp = folderWatchPath + changedPath;
        string localPath = localPathTemp.Replace(@"/",@"\");
        return localPath;
    }
```

But, When I do this the result is like

```
C:\\Users
```

But what I want to have is

```
C:\Users
```

Not "\\" but my debug shows it like `C:\\Users` but in the console it shows it as I expect it.
I want to know the reason for that
thanks..

Comment: Windows supports path names both in the format of `C:\Users` and `C:/Users`. You may not need the conversion at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `\\` is escape sequence for `\`

```
string str  = "C:\\Users";
```

is same as

```
string str  = @"C:\Users";
```

Later one is known as Verbatim string literal.

For combining paths in code it is better to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) instead of manually adding `"/"`

Your code should be like

```
public string GetLocalPath(string URI, string webResourcePath, 
                           string folderWatchPath)
{
    return Path.Combine(folderWatchPath, webResourcePath.Replace(URI, ""));
}
```

There is no need to replace `/` with `\` because path names in windows supports both. So `C:\Users` is same as `C:/Users`

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `\` is special in `""`-delimited strings. In order to get a literal `\` in a string, you double it. `\` is not special in `@""` strings, so `@"\"` and `"\\"`, or `@"C:\Users"` and `"C:\\Users"` mean exactly the same thing. The debugger apparently uses the second style in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that debug shows strings with escape chars, and to escape a `\` in a non-verbatim (not prefixed with `@`) string you have to write `\\`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! appreciate your help